# workflow rule executes and reverts back

Tags: trigger, workflow

Have a workflow rule to change the status of a case to “Open” when the customer adds a comment to the closed case. It shoots an email to the customer that the status is changed.

```
workflow rule
Evaluate the rule when "created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria"
[Comment: IsPublished = true and Case: Status = closed --> status field update]
```

When the customer enters a comment in a closed case, the comment is published, but the case status stays the same. But the customer receives an email that the status has been changed.

So when I looked into the Case History, I can see two actions performed at one block. The workflow rule was executed and the status has changed to Open and reverted back to Closed again. I thought there might be an update trigger, that executes after the workflow, is performing this action. But there is no update trigger. There is no other status change workflow. I can include the status change in the Pagereference Save method in the controller, but I'm curious in knowing what might cause this. Thanks in advance.

P.S. There is a similar workflow rule to change the status of a case to Open when the customer shoots an email. It has no trouble and functioning well.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any other workflows or field updates that update cases?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. Are there any other possibilities of leading to this.

Comment: Maybe because the email that informs the customer that the case is reopened fails to send and rolls back the transaction? Can you check the e-mail log?

Comment: In dev, I test as an user with customer profile. When testing, the workflow executes and the customer receives an email that the status is changed. I've added an image of the case history in which it shows two actions in one row.

Comment: This is interesting, there has to be some other trigger or workflow that reverts the value. I haven't seen two updates on one field in one save action before. I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: @Lex Thanks for your response. I've faced this kind of issue before in which the Case Owners change to one default queue executing a batch class, the owners were changed because of the Assignment rule. Once that was figured, the DmlOptions class was included,  

---Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;"---

in the Batchclass to retain the same owners. But this is related to the status and I'm not able to figure out. That's why I'm wondering about it.